# Bash parameter verification using regex

Tags: regex, bash

I don't how to use regex properly in bash, i got an error trying to do in this way, what is wrong in that regex verification?

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! $# -eq 1 ]; then
        echo "Error: wrong parameters"
else
        if [ $1 =~ "[a-z]" ]; then
                echo "$1: word"
        elif [ $1 =~ "[0-9]" ]; then
                echo "$1: number"
        else
                echo "$1: invalid parameter"
        fi
fi
```

Comment: For a simple check like this, consider `case`. `case $1 in *[!A-Za-z0-9]*) echo invalid;; *[A-za-z]*) echo word;; '') echo empty;; *) echo number;; esac`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have reworked your script and get the expected result with the following:

```
  #!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                      
  if [ ! $# -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "Error: wrong parameters"
  else
    if [[ $1 =~ ^[a-z]+$ ]]; then
      echo "$1: word"
    elif [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
      echo "$1: number"
    else
      echo "$1: invalid parameter"
    fi
  fi
```

You do not need to quote your Regex.

Comment: More than that, you *should not* quote the regex: from the manpage, "Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force it to be matched as a string"

Answer (score 6):

[Don't quote the regex](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#if_.5B.5B_.24foo_.3D.2BAH4_.27some_RE.27_.5D.5D), and use double brackets:

```
[[ "$1" =~ [a-z] ]]
```

It's not strictly necessary to quote the variable in this specific case, but it doesn't hurt and it's good practice to always quote strings which contain variables because of the very, very numerous pitfalls related to [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting).

Comment: Thanks l0b0, that works, can you explain why the two brackets?

Comment: The double brackets indicate the bash-specific [conditional construct](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) that implements the regex matching operator `=~`

Answer (score -1):

Use two brackets :

```
if [[ "$1" =~ [a-z] ]] ; then
```

Comment: i still get "invalid parameter"

Comment: The pattern merely checks that there is one alphabetic character, not that there are no non-alphabetics. Other answers have already provided a complete solution.

Comment: @tripleee the question asked for the proper mechanism to use reg-ex in bash, not for correctness in a regex pattern to match "words"  (although I now see that was what in fact Ramon was trying to do)